# Enable checkboxes only for leaf nodes

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there a way to enable checkboxes only for leaf nodes in [Kendo TreeView](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/index)?
One way I can think of is to disable checkboxes for all nodes and when TreeView is loaded then enable for nodes without children.
However I am not able to find `onload` event for TreeView and this will be expensive operation. Is there some way?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      let data = {
         "Level1":[
            {
               "id":"idlevel1",
               "name":"Level1",
               "Level2":[
                  {
                     "id":"idlevel2",
                     "name":"Level2",
                     "Level3":[
                        {
                           "id":"id1level3",
                           "name":"Level3_1",
                           "Level4":[
                              {
                                 "id":"id1level4",
                                 "name":"1_level4"
                              },
                              {
                                 "id":"id2level4",
                                 "name":"2_level4"
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "id":"id2level3",
                           "name":"Level3_2",
                           "Level4":[
                              {
                                 "id":"id1level4",
                                 "name":"1_level4"
                              },
                              {
                                 "id":"id2level4",
                                 "name":"2_level4"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      };

      $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
          data: data,

          schema:{
                  data: "Level1",
                  model:{
                        children:{
                              schema:{
                                    data:"Level2",
                                    model:{
                                          children:{
                                                schema:{
                                                      data:"Level3",
                                                      model:{
                                                            children:{
                                                                  schema:{
                                                                        data:"Level4"
                                                                  }
                                                            }
                                                      }
                                                }
                                          }
                                    }
                              }
                        }
                  }
            } 
        }),
                  checkboxes:{
            checkedChildren: true
          },
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="treeview"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As per @Shai we can use checkbox template with following code

```
 template: (e) => {
          return e.item.hasChildren ? '' : '<input type="checkbox" name="check' + e.item.id + '" value = "true" />';
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the checkboxes template configuration:

**Edit:**
Improved the solution using OP's comment.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Untitled</title>
        
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
        
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
          <script>
            $(function() {
              let data = {
                 "Level1":[
                    {
                       "id":"idlevel1",
                       "name":"Level1",
                       "Level2":[
                          {
                             "id":"idlevel2",
                             "name":"Level2",
                             "Level3":[
                                {
                                   "id":"id1level3",
                                   "name":"Level3_1",
                                   "Level4":[
                                      {
                                         "id":"id1level4",
                                         "name":"1_level4"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "id":"id2level4",
                                         "name":"2_level4"
                                      }
                                   ]
                                },
                                {
                                   "id":"id2level3",
                                   "name":"Level3_2",
                                   "Level4":[
                                      {
                                         "id":"id1level4",
                                         "name":"1_level4"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "id":"id2level4",
                                         "name":"2_level4"
                                      }
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              };
        
              $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                dataTextField: "name",
                dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                  data: data,
        
                  schema:{
                          data: "Level1",
                          model:{
                                children:{
                                      schema:{
                                            data:"Level2",
                                            model:{
                                                  children:{
                                                        schema:{
                                                              data:"Level3",
                                                              model:{
                                                                    children:{
                                                                          schema:{
                                                                                data:"Level4"
                                                                          }
                                                                    }
                                                              }
                                                        }
                                                  }
                                            }
                                      }
                                }
                          }
                    } 
                }),
                          checkboxes:{
                    checkedChildren: true,
                    template: (e) => {
                          return e.item.hasChildren ? "" : "<input type='checkbox' name='check" + e.item.id + "' value='true' />";
                        }
                  },
              });
            });
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="treeview"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: we dont need to change level to item. Please see my edited post.

Comment: You're right, that is better. Good job! I've editted my answer accordingly.